# Como Compilar y Generar un .WAR?

Tags: java, apache, eclipse, maven

Tengo un proyecto realizado en MAVEN con Eclipse el cual consiste en conectarse a una base de datos con APACHE y mostrar algunos datos... como y donde configuro a que base de datos conectarse? lo que hago es:
1) Run As
2) Tomcat V7 Server at localhost...
decir que la base de datos a la que deseo que se conecte la tengo en el servidor XAMPP tengo iniciados los servicios de Apache y MySQL...por lo cual me tira el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-->¿como hago para que cambiar los puertos del tomcat de JAVA?

-->una vez que lo haga como hago para indicar a que base de datos se debe conectar??
Gracias y si necesitan mas información preguntarme!!

Answer (score 1):

Podrias cambiar los puertos de tomcat, en la carpeta de tomcat /user/home/apache-tomcat-7.0.70/conf/server.xml.

Antes:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Despues:

```
<Connector port="28080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Antes:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
```

Despues:

```
<Server port="28005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
```

Antes: `<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />`

Despues: `<Connector port="28009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />`

Para compilar y generar el war solo tienes que hacer esto: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]